# Migrate django mysqlite database to mysql in ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried to migrate django mysqlite database mysql database.but can't migrate sqlite to mysql. i tried all the solutions but no use.

My code

settings.py

```
DATABSES = {
     'default' :{
         'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME'  :'MasterQuote',
         'USER'  : 'root',
         'PASSWORD' : 'root',
         'HOST' : 'localhost',
         'PORT' : ''
     }
}
```

ERROR TRACEBACK:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 79, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 206, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I tried all type of solution.I didn't add any data.my code was just initial stage

Anyone please help why this error was occurred ?

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting the spelling of DATABASES, you have written DATABSES

Answer (score 0):

There is typo mistake in spelling of **DATABASES**.

Replace

```
DATABSES = {
     'default' :{
         'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME'  :'MasterQuote',
         'USER'  : 'root',
         'PASSWORD' : 'root',
         'HOST' : 'localhost',
         'PORT' : ''
     }
}
```

with

```
DATABASES = {
     'default' :{
         'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         'NAME'  :'MasterQuote',
         'USER'  : 'root',
         'PASSWORD' : 'root',
         'HOST' : 'localhost',
         'PORT' : ''
     }
}
```